# Redirect failing - "...will never complete"

Tags: apache, redirect, cpanel

I am trying to redirect a blog page to a newly updated page. The old entry is gone, but it is indexed in Google, and other people have links to it.

I get this error: "The page isn't redirecting properly"  "Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

The (deleted) link looks like this: "http://mysite.com/blog/?p=158"

I want to redirect that to "http://mysite.com/blog/?p=194"

I used CPANEL to do a permanent (301) redirect. (I have other redirects working.)

I gues the ? is causing a problem. How do I fix it so the page redirects?

(Please give instructions for CPANEL - the server has Frontpage extensions, and I don't bother with re-researching how to do it manually - the multiple files that need updated.)

Answer (score 0):

I installed a WordPress plugin "Redirection." That solved my problem.